# Как посмотреть список всех id которые используются на странице в коде html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Как посмотреть список всех id которые используются на странице в коде html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно получить все элементы, у которых есть id, и вывести список:

```
var ids = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call( ids, function( el, i ) {
    console.log( el.id ); // log the ID
});
```

Если нужен массив из id

```
var ids = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');

var arr = Array.prototype.map.call( ids, function( el, i ) {
    return el.id;
});
```

P.S. взял с [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115022/how-do-i-enumerate-all-of-the-html-ids-in-a-document-with-javascript), автор ответа @user113716

Comment: Мне сами id нужно посмотреть, а не элементы выбирать.

Comment: @Khipster пробегитесь по выбранной коллекции и соберите их в массив)

Comment: @Khipster, в консоли браузера можно выполнить код, я добавил вывод списка id.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи jquery я бы написал как-нибудь так:

```
var ids = $('[id]').map((i, el) => el.id);
```

В принципе должно работать и так:

```
var ids = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id]'), el => el.id);
```

Comment: в вопросе нет метки `jquery` ;-)

Comment: Дополнил, но смысл тот же.

Comment: только код неверен) `document.querySelectorAll('[id!=""]')` будет ругаться на невалидность селектора......а даже если селектор был бы валиден, то дальше будет ругаться что `map is not a function`

Comment: Зато в метках были `google chrome`, `вэб-дизайн` и `вэб-программирование`. Я к тому, что релевантность тут и так сомнительная.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен с замечаниями.

Comment: @YuS всем спасибо. теги такие т.к. думал что уже готовая кнопка есть в дебагере.

Comment: @YuS тогда стоит поправить ответ до рабочего наверное %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну вот такой ещё у меня вариант (поправил ответ). Будет работать? Самому интересно, просто с телефона пишу.

Comment: @YuS осталось с jquery поправить чтоб не выдавал пустой массив %)